# Cordova-Android-Camera: How to save base64 encoded jpg to Android file system

Tags: android, image, cordova

I am succesfully creating directories, if necessary, where I want to in the Android file system on my device, a Moto X 1st gen. I am successfully saving a plain text file, but can not save a jpg file. I have the base64 encoded string of an image and it is displaying in my img tag with src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQ...". On line 17 below, I write to a file the string with "data:image/jpeg;base64," replaced with "" (empty string). Is there a conversion to binary or something I need to do before  write the file? I open the file that is written with the code snippet below in notepad++ and I see the very long base64 encoded string. Any help will be appreciated. Sorry I couldn't provide the entire code, as it is very large. I know my code works to write files, but the image file isn't writing correctly. Thanks!

```
var wpt = '01';
imageName = wpt + imageName;
var geoJSON = '{"type":"FeatureCollection","crs":{"type":"name","properties":{"name":"urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::3857"}},"features":[{"type":"Feature","properties":{"TYPE":"WAYPOINT","IDENT":"null","LAT":' + latitude + ',"LONG":' + longitude + ',"Y_PROJ":null,"X_PROJ":null,"COMMENT":"' + createDate + ' ' + createTime + '","DISPLAY":"null","SYMBOL":"null","UNUSED1":"null","DIST":null,"PROX_INDEX":"null","COLOR":"null","ALTITUDE":null,"DEPTH":null,"TEMP":null,"TIME":"null","WPT_CLASS":"null","SUB_CLASS":null,"ATTRIB":"null","LINK":null,"STATE":null,"COUNTRY":null,"CITY":null,"ADDRESS":null,"FACILITY":null,"CROSSROAD":null,"UNUSED2":"null","ETE":"null","DTYPE":"null","MODEL":"SUNSAIL","FILENAME":"' + description + '","LTIME":"null","WPT":"' + wpt + '"},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[' + coordinates + ']}}]}';
root.getFile(gisPath + '/' + gisName, { create: true, exclusive: false}, function(fileEntry) {
    fileEntry.createWriter(function(writer) {
        writer.onwriteend = function(evt) {
            root.getFile(photoPath + '/' + imageName, { create: true, exclusive: false}, function(fileEntry) {
                fileEntry.createWriter(function(writer) {
                    writer.onwriteend = function(evt) {
                        if (i == (numImages - 1)) {
                            alert('Waypoint data and images saved succesfully for later upload.');
                            clearCache();
                            clearNew();
                            $('.uploader').remove();
                        }
                    }
                    writer.write(img.src.replace(/data:image\/jpeg;base64,/, ''));
                }, function(evt) {
                    alert('Error code: ' + evt.target.error.code + '\n' + 'Error message: ' + evt.target.error.message);
                });
            }, function(evt) {
                alert('Error code: ' + evt.target.error.code + '\n' + 'Error message: ' + evt.target.error.message);
            });
        }
        writer.write(geoJSON);
    }, function(evt) {
        alert('Error code: ' + evt.target.error.code + '\n' + 'Error message: ' + evt.target.error.message);
    });
}, function (evt) {
    alert('Error code: ' + evt.target.error.code + '\n' + 'Error message: ' + evt.target.error.message);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced line 17 with

```
writer.write(b64toBlob(img.src.replace(/data:image\/jpeg;base64,/, ''), 'image/jpg', 512));
```

Here is my b64toBlob function

```
function b64toBlob(b64Data, contentType, sliceSize) {
    contentType = contentType || '';
    sliceSize = sliceSize || 512;
    var byteCharacters = atob(b64Data);
    var byteArrays = [];
    for (var offset = 0; offset < byteCharacters.length; offset += sliceSize) {
        var slice = byteCharacters.slice(offset, offset + sliceSize);
        var byteNumbers = new Array(slice.length);
        for (var i = 0; i < slice.length; i++) {
            byteNumbers[i] = slice.charCodeAt(i);
        }
        var byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
        byteArrays.push(byteArray);
    }
    var blob = new Blob(byteArrays, {type: contentType});
    return blob;
}
```

This works well with saving jpg images to the local Android file system.